# How to connect two separate set position values in python vtk?

Tags: python, vtk

I put two separate sliders for a stl to move it in X direction and Y direction.
For connecting sliders value to position I wrote the code below

```
        #First STL file
        reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
        reader.SetFileName(filename)

        self.transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
        self.transform.Scale(1, 1, 1)

        
        self.transformFilter = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
        self.transformFilter.SetTransform(self.transform)
        self.transformFilter.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
        self.transformFilter.Update()

        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        if vtk.VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5:
            mapper.SetInput(self.transformFilter.GetOutput())
        else:
            mapper.SetInputConnection(self.transformFilter.GetOutputPort())


        self.actor = vtk.vtkActor()

        
        self.vtkwidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.vtkwidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtkwidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkwidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        self.actor.SetMapper(mapper)

        self.ren.AddActor(self.actor)

        self.iren.Start()
        
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 360, 291, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider.setMinimum(-100)
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(100)
        self.horizontalSlider.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.horizontalSlider.setSliderPosition(0)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.handler)
    

        self.horizontalSlider_2 = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 410, 291, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setMinimum(-100)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setMaximum(100)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setSliderPosition(0)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.valueChanged.connect(self.handler2)

        def handler(self, value):
            self.positionx = value
            self.actor.SetPosition(value, 0, 0)
            self.iren.GetRenderWindow().Render()

        def handler2(self, value2):
            self.positiony = value2
            self.actor.SetPosition(0, value2, 0)
            self.iren.GetRenderWindow().Render()
```

but as you see when I change one direction (for example X) all applied directions(Y or Z) before that removed and stl file start to move from the beginning position(0 ,0 ,0).

Is there any way to merge these two sliders output to work together?

Or merge two handlers into one?

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags that you applied. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.actor.SetPosition(value, 0, 0)` is your problem: you explicitly set y and z coordinates to 0!

you should use current position for y and z:

```
pos = self.actor.GetPosition()
self.actor.SetPosition(value, pos[1], pos[2])
```

And similar for second handler.